# Pasting control event code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This may seem like a funny question to some but I am comming from VB so it seems a little strange. Why is it when you copy controls from another form and then copy the code into the code behind in c# it doesn't automatically bind to that control even though it has the controls name and event in Visual Studio?

I know that VB has extra code to show that it handles a controls event so it makes it a little different, but it makes it difficult to paste large amount of code from other places.. So I tend to wonder if I am missing something.

The other thing I have noticed is using VB.net in Visual Studio the code editor has a event drop down that displays all of the controls events and in C# it only shows the ones that have code in them. The only way to see all events in VS is the events column of the property explorer.

Again I am sorry for my ignorance but I would like to make sure I am being as efficient as possible and would like to make sure I don't have some options turned off or something.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, your comment deserves to be an answer.

Comment: Posted my previous comment as an answer.  Thanks @gunr2171.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common complaint for people from VB. VB.Net uses the "WithEvents/Handles" combination to allow code to handle events, which is why you can copy paste the code to a different form. C# has no such equivalent. You can do things in C#, however, that VB.Net cannot. For instance, you can wire up an event in code and the IDE will automatically insert a method stub with the correct signature for you. To do this in VB requires a separate WithEvents declaration at class level, and then you select the control/event from the dropdowns across the IDE. Neither is better, just different!

Comment: Thank you idle mind. I am happy to find out that I am not missing something, although admittedly a little disappointed that it is not as simple as vb in this aspect.

Comment: It took me a little while, but now I'm used to switching to the Form designer view, selecting a control, hitting the "Lightning Bolt" icon in the Properties Pane, finding the event I want, then double clicking to the right of it to get a method stub handler entered for me.